# Highcharts, on column or x-axis category click append job number to page url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

Here's what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/a9QwS/

I want to make it so that if a column or x-axis label gets clicked, the data on it gets appended to the url. For instance, when using php, I can do this:

```
  echo " <td style='padding: 5px;font-size: 14px; border: 1px solid black;'>
         <a class='job_num' id='showDepts' href=?job_num=".$row['Job_Num'].'>'. 
          $row['Job_Num'] . "</a></td>";
```

Lets say thats job 5000. And once that link is clicked, "?job_num={job_number}" gets added to the url and the page refreshes and loads new data at the bottom. I've got it working like this, but I've got the columns listed underneath my column chart in a table (its part of the requirement).

So how can I make it so that if a column gets clicked, the url changes to : www.example.com/budgetreporting.php?job_num=####

Comment: what is the job number for job 5000?

Comment: It would be 5000. I have highcharts pulling from a db and listing the job numbers as the categories for the x-axis. @VolkanUlukut

Comment: So instead of using drilldown, you can reload page (as you have) and then load chart with new data.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Yep thats what I'm doing. I took off the drilldown, forgot it was still in that fiddle. I'm just not sure on how to make those categories (x-axis) clickable and appending the job number to the url though?

Comment: You can use plugin which allows do that http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9QwS/1/)
here is the code without drills.

```
         point: {
                   events: {
                      click: function(e) {
                          location.href= "?job_num=" + this.category;
                      }
                   }
                }
```

in

```
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
```

Comment: Volkan can you change your code? I removed drilldown completely. Forgot to update my fiddle accordingly. Here's what my chart looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/a9QwS/

Comment: changed now. you can try.